# Code Outlining library

Tags: library, c++, c, source-code

I'm looking for a library or tool (a C++ library would be the best for me) to get code outlining information from a source code file (.c and .cpp at least, but support for other languages would be nice).

In other words I need to obtain a list of classes, stuctures, functions, etc.

You can get an idea of what I mean looking at Visual Studio Code's outline view:

[image: Visual Studio Code outline feature]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gnat Programming Studio](https://www.adacore.com/gnatpro/toolsuite/gps) has now a C/C++ mode which uses clang as a parsing library.

(free version: https://www.adacore.com/community)

It has an API, I didn't look too much into it but it's very efficient & complete. With the GPS IDE which uses clang lib, I could parse C++11 with templates without issues.

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html

note: I'm not affiliated either to clang or AdaCore (GNATPro) software. I'm just a satisfied customer.